# Python anywhere not sending email

Tags: python, email, pythonanywhere, smtplib

`Hi, i am using pythonanywhere with my python script. The script works ok on my pc and i get a email. But on pythonanywhere it does not work.

In my example i am using wrong emails and password...

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import sys


#ivanjefrajer007
# Email configuration
sender_email = "jeskaoznameni@seznam.cz"
receiver_email = ["xxx@seznam.cz"]
password = "xxx"

# Create a message object
message = MIMEMultipart()
message["From"] = sender_email
message["To"] = 'XXX'
message["Subject"] = "XXX"

html_body = """<html>
    <body>
"""
# Email content
html_body = html_body + '''
<p>Google tabulky s rekordy zde </p>
      </body>
</html>`your text`
'''
message.attach(MIMEText(html_body, "html"))

# Connect to the SMTP server
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.seznam.cz', 465) as smtp:
    print('Přihlašuji se...')
    try:
        smtp.login(sender_email, password)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Přihlášení se nepovedlo.', e)
        sys.exit()

    print('Odesílám email...')
    try:
        smtp.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string())
        smtp.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Odeslání se nepovedlo.', e)
        sys.exit()`

    print('OK')
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

From the [PythonAnywhere pricing page](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/pricing/) I read :

> Beginner: Free!
> A limited account with one web app at your-username.pythonanywhere.com, **restricted outbound Internet access** from your apps, low CPU/bandwidth, no IPython/Jupyter notebook support.
> It works and it's a great way to get started!

If you are using a free account, this is expected.

PythonAnywhere allows free users to communicate only with Gmail SMTP servers ([source](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SMTPForFreeUsers)), but your SMTP server seems to be `smtp.seznam.cz`.

They mention on the site that all paid plans have *unrestricted Internet access* so I would suggest you give this a try if you want to access internet from your programs.

Edit : add @Filip's infos

Comment: There is an option for free accounts described here https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SMTPForFreeUsers/

Comment: `smtp.seznam.cz` is the mail server, which is not allowed by PythonAnywhere

Comment: @LiteApplication which smtp mail server would you recommend me? Thanks

Comment: ShaolinMaster as in the pythonanywhere page mentioned by @Filip, the only working smtp servers are GMail's, this means you have to create a Google account and create an [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en), or use the google [Gmail API with python](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)

Answer (score 2):

There was just problem with spam filter. After i put jeskaoznameni@seznam.cz into trusted emails it started working...
For clarification i have a paid plan.